# Querying 'photos' table, but also 'bookmarks' table at same time so bookmarked photos are known

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I query for all records in a table called photos, **and** know which of the resulting photos have been bookmarked by the current user using a single query?

Here are my tables:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `photos`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `author` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The user''s Facebook ID.',
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `thumbnail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `post_date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `description` varchar(140) NOT NULL,
  `finalist` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  CONSTRAINT user_must_exist FOREIGN KEY (author)
    REFERENCES users(facebook_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `bookmarks`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookmarks` (
  `facebook_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The author''s Facebook ID.',
  `photo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT photo_should_exist FOREIGN KEY (photo_id)
    REFERENCES photos(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT user_should_exist FOREIGN KEY (facebook_id)
    REFERENCES users(facebook_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE KEY `no_duplicates` (`facebook_id`,`photo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='The user''s favourite photos.';
```

I would imagine this query would look something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    photos.*, 
    bookmarks.photo_id AS bookmark 
FROM photos
LEFT JOIN bookmarks 
    ON bookmarks.photo_id = photos.id 
    AND photos.author = 123456789
```

However this doesn't work and I receive the following MySQL error:

```
Unknown column 'photos.id' in 'on clause'
```

keyur's code worked for me after a minor typo fix which Barmar pointed out.

```
SELECT photos . * , bookmarks.photo_id AS bookmark
FROM photos
LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON photos.id = bookmarks.photo_id
AND bookmarks.facebook_id = 123456789
```

Thank you.

Editted for typo.

Editted for second typo.

Comment: Are you sure that's the error? There definitely is a `photos.id` column in your table structure. However, there's no `bookmarks.id` (used in your SELECT clause) or `photos.facebook_id` (in the ON clause) -- the `facebook_id` column is in `bookmarks`, not `photos`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are correct. That was a typo. It should have read bookmarks.photo_id - Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you query should be like this.

```
SELECT 
    photos.*, 
    bookmarks.id AS bookmark 
FROM photos
LEFT JOIN bookmarks 
    ON photos.id = bookmarks.photo_id 
    AND bookmarks.facebook_id = 123456789
```

according your table structure `photos.facebook_id` is not exist; it is in bookmarks table

Comment: Yes, my bad... photos.facebook_id should have been photos.author - updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample working code on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/753da/3). As pointed out on a comment, you do not have a `bookmarks.id` column on you `bookmarks` table and `photo.id` indeed exists on the `photos` table. Check again the error you are receiving as seems something is not correct.